# How to correctly split DLT-log file into multiple files

Tags: python, binaryfiles, dlt-daemon, dlt

I'm trying to develop a `dlt-analyzer` that would check newly generated logs "on the fly".

For this purpose I run the `dlt-receive` that outputs all the logs into *main.dlt* file. Then using Python code I split the logs into 16kB chunks with `readlines` method and put each chunk subsequently into *temp.dlt*:

```
def read_in_chunks(file_object):
     while True:
         data = file_object.readlines(16384)
         yield data

with open('main.dlt', 'rb') as f:
    for chunks in read_in_chunks(f):
        with open('temp.dlt', 'wb') as temp_dlt:
            for chunk in chunks:
                temp_dlt.write(chunk)
```

Then I run `dlt-viewer -s -csv -f <FILTER NAME>  -c temp.dlt results.csv` to get filtered results. But in most cases it doesn't work (*results.csv* file appears empty) as it seems that logs from *main.dlt* copied to *temp.dlt* ignoring dlt-headers and so `dlt-viewer` unable to correctly parse logs...
Is there a way to split DLT file with preserving message headers? Or can I somehow add missed headers automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dlt-tools package includes tool called **dlt-convert**. This is useful for splitting / combining dlt files. To extract some part of dlt log from the bigger one, the syntax is:

```
dlt_convert -b <index_from> -e <index_to> -o part.dlt full.dlt
```

In your case you could track the latest message ID in the incoming log and then do splits based on that:

```
loop:
 # remember latest now -> latest_index = ...
 dlt_convert -b <track_index> -o latest_part.dlt input.dlt
 # do smth with part.dlt ...
 # reassign: track_index = last_index
```

Thus, I don't think it's good to just split input log at random places, but you can split with dlt_convert or adapt based on its implementation splitting based on index, i.e. with 1000 messages step.

**Note however**, that dlt-viewer can also read and show logs in real time (press connect, select ECU and protocol e.g. TCP + port).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you reply! Can you elaborate a little about `message ID` and it's format? Each message has "Index", "Time"..."Payload" fields. It would be great to iterate in a loop by, for instance, current index + 100.. but how should I pass index into those `-b` and `-e` parameters? Each time I get this error `dlt-convert: symbol lookup error: dlt-convert: undefined symbol: dlt_execute_command`

Comment: From [Examples](https://github.com/COVESA/dlt-daemon/blob/master/doc/dlt-convert.1.md#examples) I see that there should be one more prameter - `-o`, but `dlt-convert -b 0 -e 100 -o '/path/to/temp.dlt' '/path/to/main.dlt'` also lead to `dlt-convert: symbol lookup error: dlt-convert: undefined symbol: dlt_execute_command`

Comment: Tried with `sudo`: `sudo dlt-convert -b 0 -e 100 -o '/path/to/temp.dlt' '/path/to/main.dlt'` and I got new file, but it has root permissions... Thanks by now. Need to dig deeper into it...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot -o option and then I used wrong term, it's "index" and not message id. Regarding missing symbol - it's loaded from shared library, so it's basically about library paths that you are missing under user that runs dlt-convert

Comment: On my ubuntu Linux shared library is loaded from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdlt.so.2, so check if you properly installed dlt-tools package